# Limit AWS SQS messages visible per second of AWS Lambda invocations per second

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, quota

I am implementing a solution that involves SQS that triggers a Lambda funcion, that uses a 3rd party API to perform some operations. 
That 3rd party API has a limit of requests per second, so I would like to limit the amount of SQS messages processed by my Lambda funtion to a similar rate.

Is there any way to limit the number of messages visibles per second on the SQS or the number of invocations per second  of a Lambda function?

[edited]

After some insights given in the comments about AWS Kinesis:
There is no lean solution by handling Kinesis parameters Batch Window, Batch size and payload size, due to the behaviour of Kinesis has that triggers the lambda execution if ANY of the thresholds and reached: 
 * Given N = the max number of request per second I can execute over the 3rd party api.
 * Configuring a Batch Window = 1 second and a Batch Size of N, back presurre should trigger the execution with more than N_MAX requests.
 * Configuring a Batch Windows = 1 secnd and a Batch Size of MAX_ALLOWED_VALUE, will be under performant and also does not guarantee executing less than N execution per second.

The simplest solution I have found is creating a Lambda with a fixed execution rate of 1 second, that reads a fixed number of messages N from SQS/Kinesis, and write those in another SQS/Kinesis, having those another Lambda as endpoint.

Comment: You can use the [reserved concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) to limit the maximum concurrency of the lambda function

Comment: If it doesn't have to be `sqs`, the other way to do it would be `kinesis` with `batch window` option.

Answer (score 4):

This is a difficult situation.

Amazon SQS can trigger multiple AWS Lambda functions in parallel, so there is not central oversight of how fast requests can be made to the 3rd-party API.

From [Managing concurrency for a Lambda function - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html):

> To ensure that a function can always reach a certain level of concurrency, you can configure the function with reserved concurrency. When a function has reserved concurrency, no other function can use that concurrency. **Reserved concurrency also limits the maximum concurrency for the function**, and applies to the function as a whole, including versions and aliases.

Therefore, concurrency can be used to limit the number of *simultaneous* Lambda functions executing, but this does not necessarily map to "x API calls per second". That would depend upon how long the Lambda function takes to execute (eg 2 seconds) and how many API calls it makes in that time (eg 2 API calls).

It might be necessary to introduce delays either *within* the Lambda function (not great because you are still paying for the function to run while waiting), or *outside* the Lambda function (by triggering the Lambda functions in a different way, or even doing the processing outside of Lambda).

The easiest (but not efficient) method might be:

- Set a **concurrency of 1**
- Have the Lambda function **retry the API call** if it is rejected

Comment: I'm in the same situation, and setting the concurrency to 1 did the trick for me. My approach is to put back the message with a **uniformely random visibility timeout** when the API gets saturated so that it balances the load on it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @John Rotenstein gave a comprehensive and detailed answer about SQS part.

If your design is limited to a single consumer than you may replace `sqs` with `kinesis` streams. By replacing it, you may use `batch window` option of kinesis to limit the requests made by consumer. Batch window option is used to [reduce the number of invocations](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/09/aws-lambda-now-supports-custom-batch-window-for-kinesis-and-dynamodb-event-sources/)

> Lambda reads records from a stream at a fixed cadence (e.g. once per second for Kinesis data streams) and invokes a function with a batch of records. Batch Window allows you to wait as long as 300s to build a batch before invoking a function. Now, a function is invoked when one of the following conditions is met: the payload size reaches 6MB, the Batch Window reaches its maximum value, or the Batch Size reaches its maximum value. With Batch Window, you can increase the average number of records passed to the function with each invocation. This is helpful when you want to reduce the number of invocations and optimize cost.